# Is there a cli command to add a database to an existing AWS/RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am using AWS RDS database service to run mysql database service.
I have read that there is no limit with Mysql in the number of databases contained in a single RDS instance.
I can then use

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password> -h<instance.rds.amazon.com> -e "create database additional_dbname"
```

My question is the following : Is there a cleaner way to achieve this, using rds-cli ? 
I have RTM, but I couldn't find any reference to such usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly said by tedder42 AWS RDS creates a single database at RDS creation time.

After creating AWS RDS, connect to it as client using

```
mysql -u <username> -h <instance.rds.amazon.com> -p <password>
```

After successfully connecting to your rds instance you can fire all queries which you can fire on your local database.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. This is the solution I used, but I wonder if doing so would have any impact on backup scripts and so on, but no, snapshot contains all the databases created.

Answer (score 2):

AWS RDS only creates a single database and root/admin user at creation time. The rest of the databases and users are created by you through a client.